# Report Viewer drill through inside jQuery Dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery, reporting-services, reportviewer, jquery-ui-dialog

We have a ssrs report viewer inside a jquery dialog. It works fine until you load a report which drills through to another report using jump to report navigation. When you click on the link to drill through we get the following message and the report fails to load.

```
ActionType = ActionParam = Parameter name: ActionType
```

The master report is passing parameters through to the second report and it would seem that these are not getting passed.

This works fine when placed outside of the jQuery dialog.